# length of video supported in html's video tag

Tags: html, video

I have a problem with video streaming. I have a file 19279141 bytes of lenght and when I want send them using "chunk transfer", On browser site video is played but not buffered like for shorter file, mayebe somebody know where can be problem ?

Answer (score 1):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html5-audio-and-video-what-you-must-know/

Have a look at "Anatomy of the Video Element" => "preload". This is what you are looking for. It seems to be the browsers decision whether to buffer the video or not.

Please note the "Monitoring download progress" section as well. It gives you an idea on how to track the progress.